# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input Promise.then (async)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add data to my database. Upon execution of my fetch method I receive the following error

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input Promise.then (async)

I have tried re-configuring the promise but am unsure if I am doing this correctly.

```
addNewBeer() {
    fetch("https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer/", {
      body: "{\"name\":\"\",\"likes\":\"\"}",//input beer name and like amount ex "{\"name\":\"Michelob Ultra\",\"likes\":\"-5\"}"
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      method: "POST"
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource + responseJson,
      });
    })
  }
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code you posted but in the response you received. Only you can debug it.

Answer (score 3):

This error `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input Promise.then (async)` happens when the response you get isn't a JSON. The error happens in this part:

```
.then(response => response.json())
```

If you omit that part, you will see that `res` isn't a JSON, probably a string.

You can try to do a `console.log` to see what is the response and then provide that in your question.